# Function with two loops

Tags: python, regex, function, loops, python-re

I want to make a function what must have  2 loops:

1. must  check that at least 2 characters (letters) are inserted
2. if the two characters are in the form that the variable must receive at the end, the variable receives the correct orthographic form.

Here is my code (but it throws me in infinite loop) [Please be indulgent im a begginer (: ] :

```
def sede():
    while True:
        import re

        var_sede_0 = input("Sede : ")

        if re.match("([a-zA-Z]+.*?){2,}", var_sede_0):
            while True:
                if var_sede_0.lower() in 'torino (to)':
                    var_sede_0 = 'Torino (TO)'
                    break

                elif var_sede_0.lower() in 'reggio calabria (rc)':
                    var_sede_0 = 'Reggio Calabria (RC)'
                    break
                else:
                    print("sbagliato")
                    continue
            break
        else:
            print("formato sbagliato")
            continue


    return var_sede_0
var_sede = sede()
```

Comment: Your indents are all wrong. Please fix.

Comment: That inner loop, if it hits your `else:` block will just loop forever. There is nothing inside that `while` loop to cause `var_sede_0` to change and so `else` will trigger over and over and over again. Do you need to ask for input once again? If so, then the second `while` loop is probably inappropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner loop is the problem:

```
while True:
    if var_sede_0.lower() in 'torino (to)':
        var_sede_0 = 'Torino (TO)'
        break

    elif var_sede_0.lower() in 'reggio calabria (rc)':
        var_sede_0 = 'Reggio Calabria (RC)'
        break
    else:
        print("sbagliato")
        continue
```

Consider that nowhere in this loop do you take in new input, so `var_sede_0` can never possibly change. Given that, if the first two predicates (if statements) evaluate to false, then you will be in an infinite loop printing out `sbagliato`. You can probably simply remove the `while True` (the inner one) and get to what you want.

It is key to note that `break` and `continue` really only affect the immediate `while` context that they are in - they will not 'speak to' the outer `while` loop.

You also probably do not want to be importing `re` on every loop. Move `import re` to the top of your file.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer led me top the right path . Now it works